# AWS IoT Button not sending email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, iot

Trying to following the tutorial at https://aws.amazon.com/iot/button/. It allows to use a click of IoT button to send an email to the specified account.

The button is configured correctly as its shown active and enabled in the console. [image: AWS IoT Console]

Clicking the button shows the following log:
[image: CloudWatch Logs]

But no email is received.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on limited information from the log and your description, there are few things that you want to check:

1. Ensure that you confirm the subscription of SNS topic (by clicking the confirmation email you get)
2. Test the Lambda function manually using this template [1]

> ```
> {
> "serialNumber": "GXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
> "batteryVoltage": "mV",
> "clickType": "SINGLE | DOUBLE | LONG"
> }
> ```

3. Make sure that the role attached to your Lambda as the proper IAM policy.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/iot/button/

Disclaimer: I don't have the AWS IoT Button (as I'm not in the US) but I've worked with AWS IoT (and other AWS services).

Comment: I did not get a conformation email for SNS topic, looked through spam and trash. Is there a way to send another activation email?

Comment: Yes, go to AWS SNS console and find the topic that you created. Click in and look for your email subscription, click "request confirmation" to resend the verification email. This is only valid if the original verification email has expired.

Comment: @CalvinBoey can you please provide me help on this issue I am facing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492204/aws-ses-emails-send-not-working-sometimes