# AWS SES emails send not working sometimes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am working in one project in which my project device is connected with my home wifi network and i am sending email & push notification if my home WIFI is poor and same if my home WIFI is again back to normal then i am sending email & push notification for WIFI OK.

I am using below code which calls the sendemail function & sendpushnotification function for WIFI OK and my main alert triggered function is called with aws lambda function which calls this **sendClearAlertMailPushNotification** function.

```
function sendClearAlertMailPushNotification(iOSPlatformApplicationArn, androidPlatformApplicationArn, txtDesc, txtLevel, txtValue, thingName, pumpId, emailDescription, realDeviceName, alarmStatus, mode, dNotificationKey, alertstatus, actualHId) {
  console.log("sendClearAlertMailPushNotification")
  
  var displayCardType = "0";
  var displayCardTypeTwo = "1";
  var hId = guid();
  var hIdTwo = guid();
  // new code for improve performance start
  if (actualHId != '') {
    hId = actualHId;
  }
  // new code for improve performance end
  getSentUserInformation(pumpId, thingName, function (err, sentUserData) {
    console.log("sentUserData", sentUserData);
    var sentInfo = [];
    var count = 0;
    var rData = sentUserData;
    var emailAckSnzBtn = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < rData.length; i++) {

      count++;
      sentInfo[i] = {};
      var email = rData[i].email;
      var name = rData[i].name;
      var emailNotification = false;
      var pushNotification = false;
      if (rData[i].emailNotification) {
        emailNotification = rData[i].emailNotification;
      }
      if (rData[i].pushNotification) {
        pushNotification = rData[i].pushNotification;
      }

      if (emailNotification) { //send email notification
        sentInfo[i].notificationsendtype = 'email';
        sentInfo[i].userid = email;
        sentInfo[i].name = name;

        sendEmailNotification(email, txtLevel, txtValue, thingName, pumpId, emailDescription, realDeviceName, hId, emailAckSnzBtn);

      } else if (pushNotification) { // send push notification
        sentInfo[i].notificationsendtype = 'push';
        sentInfo[i].userid = email;
        sentInfo[i].name = name;

        sendPushNotification(email, txtLevel, txtValue, thingName, realDeviceName, pumpId, hId, iOSPlatformApplicationArn, androidPlatformApplicationArn);

      }

      if (count === rData.length) {
        savePumpHistory(txtDesc, alarmStatus, txtValue, thingName, pumpId, mode, '', '', sentInfo, displayCardType, 1, hId, alertstatus, '', function (err, historyhid) { });
        savePumpHistory(txtDesc, alarmStatus, txtValue, thingName, pumpId, mode, '', '', sentInfo, displayCardTypeTwo, 1, hIdTwo, alertstatus, '', function (err, historyhid) { });
        updateLatestRecordValue(pumpId, thingName);
        updateLastRecepIndex(pumpId, thingName, 0);
        if (alertstatus == 0) {
          saveDNotificationData(pumpId, thingName, dNotificationKey);
        }
      }

    }

  })
}
```

and here it is sendemail function below:

```
function sendEmailNotification(email, txtLevel, txtValue, thingName, pumpId, emailDescription, realDeviceName, hId, emailAckSnzBtn) {   console.log("send email from ac power ",email, txtLevel, txtValue, thingName)   var ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01', "region": 'us-east-1' });   let urlForAcknowledgeOrSnooze = (AWS.config.region == 'us-east-1') ? 'https://test.com' : 'https://testdev.com';

  var emailBody = "<div>" +
    "<div>" +
    "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td align='center'>" +
    "<img src='https://test.com/assets/icon/ion.png' width='150' height='90' />" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table><br/>" +
    "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td align='center' style='font-size: 28px;'>" +
    "<span>Here are your device's details</span><br/><br/><br/>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table>" +
    "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td align='center' style='font-size: 28px;width:600px;'>" +
    "<span style='color:#3e3f63;padding: 10px 45px;'> " + realDeviceName + " </span>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td align='center' style='font-size: 28px;width:600px;'>" +
    "<span style='color:#3e3f63;padding: 10px 45px;'>" + txtLevel + "</span>" +
    "</td>" +
    "<td align='center' style='font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold;'>" +
    "<div style='width:600px;'>" +
    "<span style='padding: 10px 45px; border: 1px solid #3e3f63;'>" + txtValue + "</span>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table> <br/> <br/>";

  if (emailAckSnzBtn) {
    emailBody += "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" +
      "<tr>" +
      "<td align='center'>" +
      "<div>" +
      "<p>" +
      "<span style='color: #3e3f63'></span>" +
      "<a href='" + urlForAcknowledgeOrSnooze + "/#/securehome/acknowledge/" + hId + "/" + email + "/ack' style='color:#3e3f63;background-color:#3e3f63;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;margin: 4px 2px;cursor:pointer;'>ACKNOWLEDGE</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='" + urlForAcknowledgeOrSnooze + "/#/securehome/acknowledge/" + hId + "/" + email + "/shelf' style='color:#3e3f63;background-color:#3e3f63;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;margin: 4px 2px;cursor:pointer;'>SNOOZE</a>" +
      "</p>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</td>" +
      "</tr>" +
      "</table> <br/> <br/>";   }

  emailBody += "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td align='center'>" +
    "<div>" +
    "<p>" + emailDescription + "</p>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";


  console.log("email body ",emailBody)
     var eparam = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [email]
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Data: emailBody
        },
        Text: {
          Data: "Hello, this is a test email!"
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: "Notification for the device " + realDeviceName
      }
    },
    Source: "no-reply@ion.cloud",
    ReplyToAddresses: ["no-reply@ion.cloud"],
    ReturnPath: "no-reply@ion.cloud"   };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(eparam))

  ses.sendEmail(eparam, function (err, data) {
    consoleValue("After send email", thingName, JSON.stringify(data));
    if (err) {
      consoleValue("all at once email error", thingName, JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    else {
      console.log("email sent successfully")
    }   });

}
```

i put here console for emailBody it is logging whole email body but i am not sure why email is not sending i am not getting any success or failure message.

same thing happens for push notification also.

please help me on this if anyone have idea.it would be great help to me.

Comment: I have the same issue, Is there anyone knows this kind of issue resolution?